# Difference between packing and merging assemblies?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, deployment

I'm onto deploying an application that consists many DLLs. I personally do not like to have many DLL shown around my application. I consider to use a 3rd party software to combine all assemblies to output one executables. I found two options **"Merge Assemblies"** and **"Pack Assemblies"** which, after trying both, serve my purpose.

But what is the difference between **"Merge Assemblies"** and **"Pack Assemblies"**? Aren't merging and packing essentially the same thing?

Comment: What 3rd party software are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about pack and your unnamed 3rd party software but if you want to merge .net assemblies you can use ILMerge.

Check out ILMerge:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17630

Overview on ILMerge:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixingLanguagesInASingleAssemblyInVisualStudioSeamlesslyWithILMergeAndMSBuild.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mergingassemblies.aspx